# Asks to update my laptop firmware, that's a first, can anything go wrong?

Tags: updates, firmware

[image]

For about 3 years this is the first time I see something like this.
Is it safe to go ahead with it?

I remember there was a case where ubuntu OS update bricked some lenovo laptops.

Comment: Update now includes UEFI updates with these models: https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist  For more info: https://github.com/rhboot/fwupdate/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Go to manufacturer and download the latest firmware for DOS according to your device copy the firmware to usb and use freedos to do such task: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/upgrade-bios-freedos OR use offline Windoze but first if you planning to use Windoze for this, download the firmware for Windozes first not DOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is ALWAYS a risk with ANY firmware update that something can go wrong, especially if you don't let it update the way it's supposed to. That being said, I haven't seen any particular issues when I looked up the firmware mentioned here.

If you're paranoid, make sure the computer is plugged into a battery backup and have your most important files backed up on an external hard drive and with a reputable cloud service (google drive gives you 15GB free per account).

If I were you, I'd just update, I haven't really had many issues personally with Ubuntu hurting anything and I've run it on a couple of laptops, including my daily driver I rely on. Besides, keeping firmware up to date is very good for security, especially with all the Intel and AMD chip vulnerabilities being found these days.

Comment: Unfortunately the newest INTEL cpu's (the LGA 1155 and after, i think) and the newest AMD cpu's they have "Security's" that the manufacturer can spy the user and is possible to exploit them. Some "Security" options for the cpu's can be turned off from the bios and some biose's or cpu's it doesn't  give you the option to do that at all!

Comment: I mean, it does vary a bit, but yeah, it's extremely difficult, if not impossible to avoid it completely.